# How to attain siddhis?

Tags: yoga, tantra, siddhi, yoga-sutras

Is there any source that contains description of methods or mantra sadhana to attain all the siddhis? Such as x samyama for x siddhi, or methods of worshipping a yantra or deity for x siddhi? Do siddhis gaining through samyama and others still obtainable after one reaches turiya?

Comment: Tantra practices are not meant to be revealed to the people who are not part of mAndala. Only a Guru can tell you all these.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8245/647

Comment: Yes, Yoga Sutras mention Samayana done on what gives which particular Siddhi.