# Some mantras which require minimal level of efforts to make them siddha?

Tags: puranas, mantras, siddhi

Please tell some Mantras which require minimal efforts to get Siddhi over them, so that one can feel their miracle and power.

Comment: Nothing like that exists, for minimum time One must gain the matra through Diksha from the guru.

Comment: Check for Shabar mantras. They are already said to be "Su-Siddha". They start giving immediate results. For other mantras Diksha, Purascharana will be required. Not sure if Diksha is needed for Shabar mantras or not.

Comment: For Shabar mantras you can see this related question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17510/are-shabar-mantras-really-auto-energised

Comment: Related ......https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/41201/existence-of-mantras-that-does-not-need-concentration-for-attaining-siddhi

Comment: Related ..... https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8180/any-short-mantra-causing-spontaneous-visible-physical-change

Comment: I think it's a duplicate question of @hanugm question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/41201/existence-of-mantras-that-does-not-need-concentration-for-attaining-siddhi

Comment: Since the question seeks "minimal efforts", the minimal most effort for achieving Siddhi would have to be through Shaktipat where the Guru simply transfers His/Her energy to the sadhaka and they get naturally awakened. Pls refer https://www.sahajayoga.org.in/ and also https://www.quora.com/profile/Brian-Jones-339 who talks about Heartfullness.  The underlying principle still remains Shaktipat.