# Swara signs and Vedas

Tags: vedas

What is the basis of intonation marks with respect to vedic chantings? Why does it not applicable in puranic or Geeta chanting?

Comment: [related not duplicate] http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5159/3500

Answer (score 11):

Vedic hymns are represented in various [Chhanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_meter) (छंद). Which is sung in which way is determined by **Vedic Swara** (स्वर) (Vedic accent). In chanting of Vedic hymns, there are following main swara/accent used:

1. Uddata (उदात्त)
2. Anuddata (अनुदात्त)
3. Swarit (स्वरित)
4. Dheergha Swarita (दीर्घ स्वरित​)
5. Prachaya: (प्रचय​)

**Uddata** swara is sung or rendered with medium/normal pitch i.e without any raise or lowering of pitch. Uddata latters are left unmarked. It is rendered/printed usually without any mark/sign.

**Anuddata** swara is sung/rendered with lower pitch/note than Uddata. Anuddata latters are marked with horizontal bar (`_`) below the latter.

**Swaita** is sung/rendered with upper pitch/note compared to Uddata. Swarita latters are marked with vertical bar (<sup>`|`</sup>) above the latter.

**Deergha Swarita** is the extension (elongation of time) of Swarita and is sung/rendered with upper pitch/note twice (in time scale) compared to Uddata. Deergha Swarita latters are marked with double vertical bar (<sup>`||`</sup>) above the latter.

In specific instances the swara of the previous letter is carried till the next occurring AnudAtta or till the end of that pada or mantra, that is **Prachaya.**

---

There are some rules of following Swaras during chanting of Vedic mantras. Vedic Swaras is defined and described in Sanskrit Vyakarana (Panini's Ashtadhyayi) and also explained in Samaveda and in Patanjali's Mahabhashya.

You can find the Vedas with accent on [Sanskrit Documents](http://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/by-category/doc_veda.php) & on [Sanskrit Web](http://www.sanskritweb.net/).

Example screen shot of Rigveda 1.1.1 with Vedic accent in Devanagari:

> [image]

It is highly recommended to learn and study vedas under the guidance of guru. Visit [Start reading Hindu Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6726/277)

---

Referance: [Vedic accent](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%95_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%98%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4) and [Basic of Swaras](http://vedavms.in/docs/articles/01VMSBasics%20of%20Veda%20Swaras.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much for enlightening me with your illuminating reply.