# How/where Vedic chants are written down

Tags: vedic-chanting

Wondering if (a) Vedic chants are written down (I know at least in the remote past they were purely an oral tradition), and (b) where they are written down. I'm wondering if there is anywhere online (like a museum or university website perhaps, or something else) which has ancient Vedic chants written down in some sort of sheet music format or something like that. Or perhaps where might even be modern Vedic chants written down in a format.

Comment: Related or a duplicate of [Procedures used for preserving the integrity of the Vedas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9517/5212)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing like ancient and modern Vedic chants.
The same pattern is followed throughout generations.

Initially it was only oral tradition and they were perfected by reciting them in various methods which includes repetition of syllables or words or sentences in normal and reverse order.

Later they were penned down as text and to keep its mode of chanting the text is marked with special symbols which indicate the [svara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9465/7853) (tone/rhythm etc).

There are various authentic Vedic chanting available as audio video and text formats.

For audio you can refer to Sri [Prakash](https://youtu.be/BYYjZFW4ZYY) Kaushik who is a vedic pundit from South India. There are many sites which have [authentic](https://youtu.be/RYvkYk7GvJ0) vedic [recitation](https://youtu.be/bPlEZDKxhcE).

For text you can refer to websites like arya [samaj](http://www.onlineved.com) as they have vedas in devanagari script and commentaries.

Comment: Awesome, please post links if you have any, google isn't being very kind on finding them. Especially for the text.

Comment: I am just getting a bunch of [spam](https://coolsoftbox.netlify.com/arya-samaj-vedic-sandhya-pdf.html) :/

Comment: @LancePollard i have uploaded respective links in the answer please see them.

Comment: This is a start, but unfortunately the text on http://www.onlineved.com/ is as an _image_ rather than as Unicode text. I have a follow up question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29667/online-version-of-vedas-puranas-sutras-and-shastras-in-devanagari-sanskrit).

Comment: @LancePollard sir please explore the site properly. It has four vedas with hindi and English translation four vedas

Comment: I found the vedas in Hindi, one verse at a time. I also don't see where they can be downloaded. I am mainly looking for text versions of the complete vedas that can be downloaded, with the annotations for the chanting.

Comment: @LancePollard no its not possible to chant that way. You need to learn the correct chant and pronunciation from a Vedic gurukul or paathshala. Its a long process

Comment: Agnishtomo visadu ashtadasacha...

Comment: Bruhaspatirakaamayada sranne devaadadheenaRangacheyam