# Online version of Vedas, Puranas, Sutras, and Shastras in Devanagari/Sanskrit

Tags: vedas, puranas, brahma-sutras, dharma-shastras

Wondering if there are any/all of these online somewhere in a copyleft format (free / open source / public domain, or something similar to that), in the original Devanagari script in Sanskrit, in Unicode/text format (aka not in a PDF), *such that you can download the entire thing*. If there are none to be found in Unicode/text format, then a PDF would work as an alternative, but text would be best.

I have found the [Rig Veda](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/index.htm) and the [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/index.htm) and Ramayana, but not sure if there are better versions online somewhere.

Specifically looking for these. I'm only familiar with the Vedas, not the others, but would like to find them.

- Rig Veda
- Yajurveda
- Samaveda
- Atharvaveda
- [Puranas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranas#Texts)
- [Sutras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutra#Post-vedic_sutras)
- [Shastras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharma%C5%9B%C4%81stra#Contents_of_Dharmasutras_and_Dharma%C5%9B%C4%81stra) (I'm not too familiar with the texts here)

[This website](http://www.onlineved.com/) seems to suggest it has the Vedas, but I'm not sure if they have the Sanskrit versions in Devanagari (it says Hindi instead of Sanskrit, which I'm not sure if it's the exact same).

[image]

And I am also uncertain what `Kand`, `Sukta` and the rest mean, and if this is the actual text just one verse at a time.

Looking for text format in Sanskrit/Devanagari of these resources. Unfortunately this resource has made the text into an image `<canvas>` so it cannot be copied/downloaded.

[image]

[This](https://archive.org/details/Samved/page/n183) seems to be a copy of the Samaveda in Hindi, but the quality is not very good and it is a PDF rather than plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your enquiry is about scriptures of hinduism  (Vedas , Upanishads ,Puranas ) in text format which you can download or Copy-Paste. Yes some of the works are available in Sanskrit versions in Devanagari script.

---

## Puranas

[**Wikisource**](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D) is the best website for Puranas in Devnagari. Here we can find sanskrit verses  of all 18 puranas plus some upapuranas  , which we can either copy-paste or simply can download.

---

## Upanishads

[**Upanishad**](https://www.upanishads.iitk.ac.in/) mantras in Devanagari   are also available  over  the website developed  by IIT Kanpur . Interestingly you will here fins the english translation of the upanishads also with commentaries. Here we can find 11 principal upanishads.

---

## Sutras

There are lots of Sutras in Hinduism scripture , I am here just providing links for two i.e.[**Yoga-Sutras**](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/yogasutra_content?language=dv&field_chapter_value=1&field_nsutra_value=1&enable_sutra=1&enable_bhaysa=1&enable_vritti=1)   by Maharshi Patanjali and [**Brahma-Sutras**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_major_works/brahma_suutra.html?lang=sa) by Shree Veda Vyasa.
Here is Patanjali Yoga-Sutras in Devanagari.  Here Sutras are denoted by numbers like 1..1 etc. and below is the sanskrit commentary.

- Here is [**Narada Bhakti Sutras**](https://wiki.yoga-vidya.de/Bhakti_Sutra_Sanskrit_Text) Sanskrit Text.

---

## Vedas

on Sanskrit Documents web site we can find [**Rig-Veda Samhita**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/veda/) (core texts)  and [**Sama-Veda Samhita (Kauthuma Shakha i.e. Kauthuma branch )**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/sv-kauthuma.html?lang=sa)  in Devanagari script , the content of which we  can copy-paste.

---

Regarding your enquiry about the Kand, Sukta . In Sanskrit sukta  means "well said", "well told. the vedic  hymns are called "sukta" . There are various Suktas (Hymns) like Purusha-Sukta , Shree-Sukta etc.

Kanda literally means Chapter and is sanskrit word of the same.

Dharma-Shastras (धर्मशास्त्र, dharma-shastra) is a category of Hindu literature containing important instructions regarding religious law, ethics, economics, jurisprudence and more. It is categorised as smṛti, an important and authoritative selection of books dealing with the Hindu lifestyle.

Shastras   means science , but the word Shastras  is not only limited to Dharma-Shastras. The word Shastras is  general word  used for  all scriptures of hinduism i.e. **Shastras= common word for  all scriptures of Hinduism.**

Comment: Awesome, that puranas link will be great! Unfortunately the https://sanskritdocuments.org website has the copyright restriction that they are only for personal use :/

Comment: @LancePollard -Thank you also for your enquiry. All the users who want sanskrit verses  of scriptures will get them at one place here in this  answer. Users also can add links in answer to make it more and more comprehensive.

Comment: I haven't found any other sutras, and that website only has the two I think. Would be awesome if links to where all of them could be found are posted :)

Comment: @LancePollard Yes I will try to find such a place or else i will update the answer by adding individual links later because of vastness of sutra literature.

Comment: I think all these links are present in the linked duplicate question. Vedas, Puranas, smritis all.. if not, we can edit that answer. Answering duplicate question is not a good way.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Yes , OP specifically wanted the links of scriptures in text format which he can download. So this will be a separate answer just for this purpose and also as a database. :-)

Comment: You may also want to add [Vedic Reserve](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/index_of_vedic_literature.htm), though Sanskrit (Devanagari) text available in pdf format.

Comment: And sanskritdocuments.org have collection of resources at [Text Elsewhere](https://sanskritdocuments.org/TextsElsewhere/) page :)

Comment: This answer should go to the original question. The original question also has different types of texts (more than you gave). That has been the canonicl question since long. Dupes are closed to prevent repetition. Repetition is unnecessary, waste of reviewers time and your time. Avoid answering duplicates. That gives unfair advantage. At least, as a high rep user, you might want to do that . @Pandya I think that is already present in the original. Repeating answers is unnecessary and a waste of time..

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Agree, I thought as questioner asked with specific/certain condition "[Copyleft](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/copyleft.en.html) text in Sanskrit/Devanagari"

Comment: Yes this is about _text_ (unicode) in Devanagari (from Sanskrit) specifically. PDFs are in many places (especially low-quality PDFs), but I would like plain text.

Comment: @Pandya yeah that vedicreserve site has some decent quality pdfs, wondering if you know if they have any unicode text versions though.

Comment: @LancePollard Yes, I think [TheDestroyer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer) know it.

Comment: Can i get srirudram in sanskrit text

Comment: Wondering if the texts [here](http://www.onlineved.com/yajur-ved/?mantra=1) are in Sanskrit, or if Hindi is different from Sanskrit.

Comment: Also wondering if the Puranas on WikiSource are in Hindi or Sanskrit.

Comment: [Here](http://www.peterffreund.com/Vedic_Literature/Vedic%20Literature%20Unicode/Purana/) are some Puranas, though not sure the quality/completeness. [Here](http://www.peterffreund.com/shiksha/hamburg_atreya_shiksha_codex.html) are some texts called Śhikṣhā, not sure what that means.

Comment: [More info here](http://rsvidyapeetha.ac.in/website/VEDASASTRA.html).

Comment: What about the atharvaveda or yajurveda, I haven't found those anywhere...

Comment: I will try.   I came across some  previously, but  they were mostly  incomplete.

Comment: BTW Hindi is completely different from sanskrit but Devanagari is used in both. For Shiksha see - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiksha